# Difference between OptionalInt and int?

Tags: java, java-8

```
OptionalInt max = IntStream.of(arr).max();
```

Or

```
int maximum = 0;
for (int i : arr) {
     maximum = Math.max(i, maximum);
}
```

Both these methods return maximum value. What does `OptionalInt` make a difference? As per the definition of `OptionalInt`, if value is present it returns `getAsInt()` but if value is not present, it throws an `Exception`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The advantage of using the stream approach over the imperative approach is that when there are no elements in the array `arr` then we represent *the maximum value* as *absent* to indicate *a missing value*.

regarding this description you've stated:

> As per the definition of OptionalInt,if value if present it returns
>   getasIntValue() but if value is not present ,it throws Exception.

Note that it throws an exception only when you call [getAsInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html#getAsInt--) directly from an optional result and the value is *absent*.

This is a good thing in the sense that when we attempt to access the element using [getAsInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html#getAsInt--) as you've mentioned and there is no value present then a `NoSuchElementException` will be thrown and in-fact getting an exception, in this case, might be useful because you now know there is no value present whereas the imperative approach could lead to hiding a bug because if the array is empty then the maximum value is `0` which is false except in a certain scenario mentioned in my 2nd to last paragraph below.

Such, small code as you've shown will probably be easy to fix when there is a bug but in production code, it may be hard to find due to the size of the codebase.

if `0` is, in fact, the default you want to provide when the array is empty then you can proceed with the imperative approach as is or using the optional approach it could be done as:

```
int max = IntStream.of(arr).max()
                   .orElse(0);
```

In the above scenario, the `NoSuchElementException` exception will not be thrown. Also, I'd recommend not to use [getAsInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html#getAsInt--) straight from an optional result unless you're 100% sure the array will not be empty. rather utilise [orElse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html#orElse-int-), [orElseGet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.IntSupplier-) or [orElseThrow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-) depending on which you find most appropriate for the given situation.

Comment: Yes thats true. I have a huge codebase,multiple List<string> or List<Product> type are getting populated and if they are null,we basically want to skill that list or array . I thought the best approach is 
             `Optional.ofNullable(productlist).orElseThrow(e->e.emptyList()).stream.foreach(e-> e.getId());`

Answer (score 3):

In your first snippet, if `arr` is empty, there is no maximum value. The `OptionalInt` would be empty (i.e. it would contain no value).

In your second snippet, if `arr` is empty, the maximum is `0` by default.

Implementing the logic of the first snippet without an `OptionalInt` can be done using an `Integer` variable, which can contain a `null` value:

```
Integer maximum = null;
for (int i:arr) {
     maximum = maximum != null ? Math.max(i,maximum) : i;
}
```

Now `maximum` will remain `null` if `arr` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that when `arr` is empty then `max` will be "empty" while maximum is 0, which is technically incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

OptionalInt allows us to create an object which may or may not contain a int value. If a value is present, **isPresent()** will return true and **getAsInt()** will return the value.

Additional methods that depend on the presence or absence of a contained value are provided, such as orElse().

Other classes similar to OptionalInt are OptionalFloat, OptionalDouble, Optional.
These can help us eliminate exceptions that occur due to the absence of a value at runtime.

> Here's an example of OptionalDouble

```
public class SumAndAverage {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    persons.add(new Person("Joe", 55));
    persons.add(new Person("Moe", 33));
    persons.add(new Person("Hill", 94));


    OptionalDouble average = persons.stream().mapToInt(p -> p.getAge()).average();

    if (average.isPresent()) {
        System.out.println(average.getAsDouble());
    } else {
            System.out.println("Could not calculate average.");
    }
}
```

}